# sudo aptitude remove compizconfig-settings-manager error

Tags: package-management, compiz, aptitude

i tried to remove compizconfig-settings-manager with aptitude but i got:

```
gigiux@Gigiux:~$ sudo aptitude remove compizconfig-settings-manager
[sudo] password for gigiux: 
The following packages will be REMOVED:  
  compizconfig-settings-manager python-compizconfig{u} 
The following partially installed packages will be configured:
  alacarte bluefish-data ipython ipython-notebook ipython-qtconsole 
  ninja-ide pyflakes pylint python-antlr python-astroid python-cvxopt 
  python-cycler python-dateutil python-egenix-mxdatetime 
  python-egenix-mxtools python-jdcal python-jedi python-joblib 
  python-lazy-object-proxy python-logilab-common python-matplotlib 
  python-mpmath python-numexpr python-openpyxl python-pandas python-patsy 
  python-psutil python-py python-pyflakes python-pyglet python-pyinotify 
  python-pymysql python-pyparsing python-pyside python-pyside.phonon 
  python-pyside.qtcore python-pyside.qtdeclarative python-pyside.qtgui 
  python-pyside.qthelp python-pyside.qtnetwork python-pyside.qtopengl 
  python-pyside.qtscript python-pyside.qtsql python-pyside.qtsvg 
  python-pyside.qttest python-pyside.qtuitools python-pyside.qtwebkit 
  python-pyside.qtxml python-pytest python-simplegeneric python-simplejson 
  python-spyderlib python-statsmodels python-sympy python-tables 
  python-tornado python-wrapt python-xlrd python-xlwt python-zmq 
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 to remove and 170 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 4,830 kB will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n/?] y
dpkg: error processing package compizconfig-settings-manager (--remove):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting a removal
dpkg: python-compizconfig:amd64: dependency problems, but removing anyway as you requested:
 compizconfig-settings-manager depends on python-compizconfig (>= 1:0.9.12.2+16.04.20160526-0ubuntu1).

(Reading database ... 484123 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing python-compizconfig:amd64 (1:0.9.12.2+16.04.20160823-0ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 compizconfig-settings-manager
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
Failed to perform requested operation on package.  Trying to recover:
Setting up python-wrapt (1.8.0-5build2) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-wrapt (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up python-simplejson (3.8.1-1ubuntu2) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-simplejson (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up alacarte (3.11.91-2) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package alacarte (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up python-lazy-object-proxy (1.2.1-1build1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-lazy-object-proxy (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up python-numexpr (2.4.3-1ubuntu1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-numexpr (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up python-simplegeneric (0.8.1-1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-simplegeneric (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up python-logilab-common (1.1.0-1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-logilab-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up python-egenix-mxtools (3.2.9-1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-egenix-mxtools (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up python-py (1.4.31-1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-py (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up python-pymysql (0.7.2-1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-pymysql (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up python-cvxopt (1.1.4-1.4) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-cvxopt (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up python-jedi (0.9.0-1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-jedi (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up python-joblib (0.9.4-1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-joblib (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up python-jdcal (1.0-1build1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-jdcal (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ipython:
 ipython depends on python-simplegeneric; however:
  Package python-simplegeneric is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package ipython (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up python-tornado (4.2.1-1ubuntu3) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-tornado (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up python-pyglet (1.1.4.dfsg-3) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-pyglet (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ipython-notebook:
 ipython-notebook depends on ipython (= 2.4.1-1); however:
  Package ipython is not configured yet.
 ipython-notebook depends on python-tornado (>= 3.1.0); however:
  Package python-tornado is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package ipython-notebook (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-pytest:
 python-pytest depends on python-py (>= 1.4.29); however:
  Package python-py is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python-pytest (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up python-cycler (0.9.0-1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-cycler (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up python-pyinotify (0.9.6-0fakesync1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-pyinotify (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up python-dateutil (2.4.2-1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-dateutil (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-openpyxl:
 python-openpyxl depends on python-jdcal; however:
  Package python-jdcal is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python-openpyxl (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up python-xlrd (0.9.4-1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-xlrd (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up python-pyside.qtcore (1.2.2-2build2) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-pyside.qtcore (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up python-psutil (3.4.2-1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-psutil (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up python-pyflakes (1.1.0-2) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-pyflakes (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up bluefish-data (2.2.7-2) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package bluefish-data (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-pyside:
 python-pyside depends on python-pyside.qtcore (>= 1.2.2-2build2); however:
  Package python-pyside.qtcore is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python-pyside (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up python-spyderlib (2.3.8+dfsg1-1build1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-spyderlib (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-egenix-mxdatetime:
 python-egenix-mxdatetime depends on python-egenix-mxtools; however:
  Package python-egenix-mxtools is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python-egenix-mxdatetime (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-pyside.qtscript:
 python-pyside.qtscript depends on python-pyside.qtcore (= 1.2.2-2build2); however:
  Package python-pyside.qtcore is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python-pyside.qtscript (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up python-antlr (2.7.7+dfsg-6ubuntu1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-antlr (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-tables:
 python-tables depends on python-numexpr; however:
  Package python-numexpr is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python-tables (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-astroid:
 python-astroid depends on python-lazy-object-proxy; however:
  Package python-lazy-object-proxy is not configured yet.
 python-astroid depends on python-wrapt; however:
  Package python-wrapt is not configured yet.
 python-astroid depends on python-logilab-common (>= 0.63.0); however:
  Package python-logilab-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python-astroid (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up python-zmq (15.2.0-0ubuntu4) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-zmq (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up python-mpmath (0.19-3) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-mpmath (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up python-patsy (0.4.1-2) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-patsy (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ninja-ide:
 ninja-ide depends on python-pyinotify; however:
  Package python-pyinotify is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package ninja-ide (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up python-pyparsing (2.0.3+dfsg1-1ubuntu0.1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-pyparsing (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-xlwt:
 python-xlwt depends on python-antlr; however:
  Package python-antlr is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python-xlwt (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of pylint:
 pylint depends on python-astroid (>= 1.4.1); however:
  Package python-astroid is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package pylint (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-pyside.qtgui:
 python-pyside.qtgui depends on python-pyside.qtcore (= 1.2.2-2build2); however:
  Package python-pyside.qtcore is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python-pyside.qtgui (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-pyside.qtxml:
 python-pyside.qtxml depends on python-pyside.qtcore (= 1.2.2-2build2); however:
  Package python-pyside.qtcore is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python-pyside.qtxml (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ipython-qtconsole:
 ipython-qtconsole depends on ipython (= 2.4.1-1); however:
  Package ipython is not configured yet.
 ipython-qtconsole depends on python-zmq (>= 2.1.11); however:
  Package python-zmq is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package ipython-qtconsole (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-pandas:
 python-pandas depends on python-dateutil; however:
  Package python-dateutil is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python-pandas (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-pyside.phonon:
 python-pyside.phonon depends on python-pyside.qtgui (= 1.2.2-2build2); however:
  Package python-pyside.qtgui is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python-pyside.phonon (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-matplotlib:
 python-matplotlib depends on python-dateutil; however:
  Package python-dateutil is not configured yet.
 python-matplotlib depends on python-pyparsing (>= 1.5.6); however:
  Package python-pyparsing is not configured yet.
 python-matplotlib depends on python-cycler; however:
  Package python-cycler is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python-matplotlib (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-pyside.qthelp:
 python-pyside.qthelp depends on python-pyside.qtgui (= 1.2.2-2build2); however:
  Package python-pyside.qtgui is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python-pyside.qthelp (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of pyflakes:
 pyflakes depends on python-pyflakes (>= 1.0.0-2); however:
  Package python-pyflakes is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package pyflakes (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-pyside.qtsql:
 python-pyside.qtsql depends on python-pyside.qtgui (= 1.2.2-2build2); however:
  Package python-pyside.qtgui is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python-pyside.qtsql (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python-wrapt
 python-simplejson
 alacarte
 python-lazy-object-proxy
 python-numexpr
 python-simplegeneric
 python-logilab-common
 python-egenix-mxtools
 python-py
 python-pymysql
 python-cvxopt
 python-jedi
 python-joblib
 python-jdcal
 ipython
 python-tornado
 python-pyglet
 ipython-notebook
 python-pytest
 python-cycler
 python-pyinotify
 python-dateutil
 python-openpyxl
 python-xlrd
 python-pyside.qtcore
 python-psutil
 python-pyflakes
 bluefish-data
 python-pyside
 python-spyderlib
 python-egenix-mxdatetime
 python-pyside.qtscript
 python-antlr
 python-tables
 python-astroid
 python-zmq
 python-mpmath
 python-patsy
 ninja-ide
 python-pyparsing
 python-xlwt
 pylint
 python-pyside.qtgui
 python-pyside.qtxml
 ipython-qtconsole
 python-pandas
 python-pyside.phonon
 python-matplotlib
 python-pyside.qthelp
 pyflakes
 python-pyside.qtsql
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.

Current status: 1 (+1) broken.
```

how can I overcome this error? this compizconfig is ruining all installations, thus I can't install or remove anything else from the machine. I tried different options including 'apt-get -f install'

thanks

gigiux

Answer (score 0):

> dpkg: error processing package compizconfig-settings-manager (--remove):
>    package is in a very bad inconsistent state; **you should
>    reinstall it before attempting a removal**

Try reinstalling compizconfig-settings-manager (ccsm) before removing it. Obviously, I'm not using your machine so I don't know for certain that this will work. You say you cannot install or remove anything but you don't explicitly say you can't install ccsm. It sounds like it hasn't installed correctly or that you have accidentally removed a package that ccsm depends upon to work.

Comment: i tried reinstalling it many time (for instance with 'sudo aptitude install compizconfig-settings-manager') but it does not work (I got 'Processing was halted because there were too many errors. Current status: 0 (-1) broken').  This started when I installed python 3.5, might somehow affect ccsm? maybe it is looking for some wrong files?